# difference between two cells of consecutive columns using vba

Tags: excel, vba

my data is like:
    col A  col B col C..........up to col Q K( 453)

```
row 1:   5   7...............up to col Q K(453)
.
.
.
row 19:.....
```

basically my data has 19 rows and 453("Q K") columns.
now i want to find a difference between consecutive columns 
for example:

column B - column A = answer should be stored in next sheet (lets say in sheet 2 in "column A" of sheet 2)

i have a code for this given below, code is working, but the problem is, this code saves the result in 'range C' of same sheet and i have to write the difference formula again and again in the code so it become a overhead for me and i am a beginner of VBA-excel programming..please help me.

code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub minus()
Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer
lastRow = 404

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        C.Range("C" & i).Formula = "=B" & i & "-A" & i
    Next i

End With
End Sub
```

correction:

my data is like:

```
col 1        col 2...........    col QK
district 1   6 ..............    8
district 2   19................9
.
.
.
district 19   78...............90[this is data , columns= 453(not shown in image), this is just a snapshot of few columns ,  rows = 19][1]
```

now i want to find a difference between consecutive columns and result must be stored in sheet 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one

```
Sub minus()
Dim lastRow As Integer, lastColumn As Integer, i as Integer, j As Integer
lastRow = 19
lastColumn = 452
for i = 2 to lastColumn
    for j = 1 to lastRow
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, i).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, i+1).value - Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, i).value
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

This code will make your data in Sheet2 static, so any changes in Sheet1 will not change data in Sheet2.

**UPDATE:** I changed my answer, according to correction you made in question.